# Compiles fine on my system, was compiling in GitHub Action, now fails

Tags: blazor, github-actions, blazor-server-side

The following code has been compiling fine for months. And now, all of a sudden, it won't compile on Git (GitHub Action). It still compiles fine on my system.

```
<DisplayFlyweight Data="tagInfo.DataItem"
                  ButtonCssClass="@DisplayFlyweight.CloseButtonClass"
                  Click="@(new EventCallback(null, tagInfo.RemoveTagAction))"
                  SizeMode="SizeMode.Small" />
```

I commented out `Click="@(new EventCallback(null, tagInfo.RemoveTagAction))"` and checked in - then it compiled fine.

The error is:

```
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback' to 'System.MulticastDelegate?'
Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
```

The declaration for Click is:

```
   [Parameter]
   public EventCallback<IItemFlyweight?> Click { get; set; }
```

And RemoveTagAction (DexExpress class) is:

```
public Action RemoveTagAction { get; internal set; }
```

How can I get this compiling again? The code compiles and runs fine on my system.

thanks - dave

Comment: And did you upgrade to .net 8 already?  I think GitHub did. This might be a breaking change.

Comment: @ℍℍ Yes I did, about a month ago. And specified it in my action, again about a month ago. I've submitted a support ticket to GitHub and so should get an answer from them in about 6 weeks...

Comment: Too many  unknowns to answer the question, but I'm interested why you declare Click as an EventCallback and then pass it a null targeted EventCallback constructed on the fly - this all seems to be - at the very least - strange, if not outright bad. I assume you construct a null targeted EventCallback to prevent automatic re-rendering - why not just stick to Action in that case?

Comment: @MisterMagoo That is a work-around for a bug in the DevEx code. No idea why it works but it requires calling it that way. Got that answer from DevEx.